# Django toolbar not displaying properly

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using django 1.6.4 and django toolbar version django-debug-toolbar==1.2.

I do get the toolbar on the side but when I click on any of the menu items, it shows me the html elements from my home page within the toolbar overlay. I have done collectstatic after installing django toolbar. HTML generated is not valid but issue seems to be from the css and scripts tag from django toolbar.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Updated:
urls.py entry

```
if settings.DEBUG:
import debug_toolbar

urlpatterns += patterns('',
                        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
)
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)


THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (    
'suit',
'debug_toolbar',
'south',
'crispy_forms',
'haystack',
'taggit',
)
```

Comment: Have you tried to refresh/clear browser cache? There might be old cached stylesheets...

If it doesn't help: How do you setup django toolbar in settings, urls, etc?

Comment: Updated to add settings.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar: Did you resolve this?